# Wordpress : exclude a term from the_terms()

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a theme for a customer.

To display post taxonomies, the theme use the_terms(). It is working well. But I have a featured category that I do not want to display. So basically, I need something to check if the current term != "featured" for that function (the_terms() is used on the whole templates).

I read the codex ( http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_terms#Parameters ), but there's nothing about excluding particular terms...

The code (not helpful but someone asked me):

```
<?php the_terms($post->ID, 'portfolio_category', '', ', ', ''); ?>
```

Any help ?

EDIT :
Now I can filter the terms with :

```
add_filter('get_the_terms', 'modify_term_list', 1);
  function modify_term_list($terms){
  foreach($terms as $term_index => $term_object){
    if($term_object->name === 'A la une'){
      unset($terms[$term_index]);
      return $terms;
    }
  }
}
```

The term "A la Une" (featured) is not displaying no more. But on the 4 terms I got, only one is now displayed.

Comment: paste your actual coding part...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on boom_Shiva's code :

```
add_filter('get_the_terms', 'modify_term_list', 1);
 function modify_term_list($terms){
  foreach($terms as $term_index => $term_object){
   if($term_object->name === 'A la une'){

    unset($terms[$term_index]);

   }
   else {
    return $terms;
   }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is to not list a particular term like "Test"

```
add_filter('get_the_terms', 'modify_term_list', 1);
function modify_term_list($terms){
   foreach($terms as $term_index => $term_object){
    if($term_object->name == 'Test'){
        unset($terms[$term_index]);
        return $terms;
    }
   }
}
```

You can replace the "Test" with your **TERM NAME**

Comment: And Mobile is not displayed?? can you show me your code?, Also if you can check your error log.

Comment: Well, it's like the code you gave me search for the term "A la une" in the array, and if it is found, it exclude "A la Une" from the terms array. If it doesn't find "A la Une", it does nothing. Example : a post which have "A la Une, Mobile" terms, the term list displayed will be > "Mobile". A post with "Web, Mobile" terms will show no terms.

Comment: Yes I didn't make a strict check, if you need you can add it.